# NFC plugin doesn't work in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, nfc, ndef

I want to test an application which is written for a `NFC` based device, In my `Eclipse` when I go for installing a new software and paste the link below, I receive this error:
link:  http://nfc-eclipse-plugin.googlecode.com/git/nfc-eclipse-plugin-feature/update-site/

Error:

```
 Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
 NDEF Editor will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.
```

But I can not run my application,because there is an exclamation mark next to the name of my project!

Would you please tell me what should I do?I' m really new in Android developing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of that plugin.

1. The plugin seems already installed, so you cannot reinstall, and no updates have been issued (in the last month), so there is no update available either.
2. The plugin does not affect whether projects can be run or not, it purely a file editor for a non-executable format. There exists no functionality to validate files or projects.

Go to the problems view and see what is listed there.

```
Window->Show View->Other->General->Problems.
```

Resolve the problems. It might help to close unrelated projects. If you still feel there is a bug with the plugin, file a detailed bug report on the site.

You also might want to clean and rebuild your workspace.

```
Project->Clean
```

Comment: Great! If you have any feature requests, post them on the website :)